# YouTube API v3, How to Get fileDetails (filename, etc) for a videoresource?

Tags: youtube-api

In YouTube API v3, I'm trying to get fileDetails (filename, etc) for the various videos on my own channel.

This link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos (scroll down to "fileDetails") ...

"The fileDetails object encapsulates information about the video file that was uploaded to YouTube, including the file's resolution, duration, audio and video codecs, stream bitrates, and more. This data can only be retrieved by the video owner."

... suggests you need to be the video owner, which I AM.

Despite many hours researching and some experimenting, I still don't understand where I need to get my owner id from, and where I have to use it.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fileDetails may not be available for all the videos, but for the ones that have it,

- you need to have an authorized videos->list call while [part field](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list) has "fileDetails" and videoId set to that video.

Your application needs to implement [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) for it.

You can easily try this functionality with [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list). On the top right corner, turn on the Authorization switch and authorize the request from the dialog window. Then you can set part = fileDetails and id = VIDEO_ID

Comment: Thank You @Ibrahim.

After investigating what you said above against what I have already written, my code was closer then I thought in returning fileDetails, I guess most of my videos simply don't have available fileDetails. I'll have to make the most of what is available.

What I am trying to do is write a client that will manage content/sync between a growing number of local videos and videos I've uploaded, thus the need to match fileDetails.

If I need in future to do all of this for other users, how do I deal with the issue of video ownership? Does the client simply log into their account?

Comment: Hi, we found that this is a bug and working on to fix that. Cheers.

Comment: Thank You Ibrahim.
I didn't see this message when you first posted it and thus is why it took so long to respond. Much Appreciated.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya Can we get fileDetails of any video for streaming using official API to avoid ads, less reliable solutions like youtube-dl to play in VR for example? Do you know how to solve buffering like these guys are doing https://github.com/therealvk/DLvidHUT-Video-Downloader demo of the app included?