# Api YouTube V3: Can't get videoStreams from fileDetails

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get the fileDetails for a YouTube video. I'm able to get the following information:

> 'fileDetails' => array(       'fileSize' => 'XXX',        'fileType' => 'XXX',
>         'container' => 'XXX'    )

But it's still missing some fileDetails information, such as `videoStreams`.

I did authenticate with Oauth2 and there are some videos that give me the information I need, but there are others for which I can't get the videoStreams data.

Comment: Are you the owner for all of the videos for which you're trying to get fileDetails? Note that not all videos may have this fileDetails information available. Have you tested it using the API explorer as detailed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18497901/4241842) answer?

Comment: Yes i the owner. But not all videos i can get the videoStreams...

Comment: Try using the API explorer and if you can't get the information that way, then it just doesn't exist for that video.

Comment: Thanks!. I find in the api explorer but i find the same if i`m not the owner i not get the fileDetails. But i get this, but not get the videoStreams what is in fileDetails(bring me some videos and other information not ). Sory for my english.

Comment: Not all information is available for all videos, therefore you might not be able to get the videoStreams data for certain videos, even if you're the owner.